# removing extension mod_rewrite is too tolerant

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite `example.com/news.php` to `example.com/news` or `example.com/news/`. With my code `example.com/news` works just fine but `example.com/news/` gives me a **404 Not Found**.

My code:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

        RewriteRule ^games/csgo/([0-9]+)$ /games/csgo/view.php?id=$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

How can I redirect `example.com/news.php` to `example.com/news` AND `example.com/news/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better stick to one url type! (with or without trailing slash) and redirect the wrong type to the other,

this code is for removing slash from the end of url :

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` before that it works also with sub directories.

Comment: If i add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` before that it works also with sub directories. Thank you very much!